# How to Forward a template pack

Tags: c++, oop, templates, variadic-templates

i want to forward a variadic template pack and another template pack like this:

```cpp
template<class t, class... targs, class... args_t>
t create(argst_t&&... args)
{
   return t<targs...>(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
}
```

`t` is not a templated class, only the constructor is templated.

it is supposed to be called like this:

```cpp
class a{
public:
    template<class... args_t>
    a(args_t... args) {}
};

int main()
{
    create<a, int, float>(10, 5.5);
}
```

this should call `a::a`with the arguments 10 as an integer an 5.5 as a float.

is this possible and if how?

Comment: `return t<targs...>(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);`

Comment: anyway how you what us this thing. How compiler can say what is `targs` when `create` is invoked? Please provide [mcve] and show how this `create` suppose to be used, since your definition can't work. Please show multiple examples how this function will be used.

Comment: All parameter packs must be expanded with `...`: Presumably you want `t<targs...>`. Then, since `t` is clearly not meant to be a type, but a template, it should be a template template parameter `template<template<class...> class t, class... args_t, class... targs>`. Then the return type needs fixing. Also, you probably want the two parameter packs to be the other way around in the template head. Otherwise you can't let `args_t` be deduced automatically while specifying `targs` explicitly. Also check whether you don't really just want CTAD instead of this construction. What is the use case?